# How to get rid of white space at bottom of screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### The Problem

[image]

There is this pesky white space at the bottom of my screen and it won't go away even though I do `margin-bottom: 0` or `padding-bottom: 0`.

If someone could get rid of this white space at the bottom it would be very much appreciated!

### My Code

*HTML*

```
<div class="container-fluid no-lr-padding no-b-padding">
 ....
<div id="Menu" class="row-fluid no-b-padding">
            <div id="Menu-Header" class="header">
                <h1>Problems</h1> 
            </div>
            <div class="panel-group" id="problem-panels">
                <div class="panel panel-default top-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            Cox Subtraction Level 1c
                        </h4> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                <li class="active"><a>11</a></li>
                                <li><a>12</a></li>
                                <li><a>13</a></li>
                                <li><a>14</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">
                            Cox Addition Level 3b
                        </h4> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">panel body 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default bottom-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3">
                            Cox Subtraction Level 2a
                        </h4> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">panel body 3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.no-b-padding{
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv7Lg7jx/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the bottom margin from your problem-panels div:

```
#problem-panels {
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bkyy0ovb/)